# Trying to match interlocking vinyl floor tile 6" x 36" x 1/8"

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I would not ask this if I had not first done a lot of research.  Shown is an interlocking vinyl floor tile from the home we bought.  I've done some changes to the floor signature and would like to match this to fill in some spots.

I have searched in-person and online for both Lowes and Home Depot, and my 75% certainty is they would have gone there (trust me these people did things cheaply).  Or maybe the actually had a contractor do this.

Either way if you have a lead on which manufacturer and model I'd appreciate it.  They are 6" W x 36" L x 1/8" T (actually just a small bit thicker than 1/8")

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]
[image: picture 3]
[image: picture 4]
[image: picture 5]
[image: picture 6]
[image: picture 7]

Comment: How close of a match are you expecting?  Even with new flooring, the best matches are from the same batch number, a different batch number of the same flooring might only be close.  Plus your flooring has had a few years of use and probably faded from new, so even the same batch will be a bit different now.

Comment: At this point I'm just trying to find the manufacturer and model so I can get a good interlock.  The brands all have "about" the same interlock but not exactly is what I've found.  I can tolerate some color difference.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. That flooring sounds like the product that the 2 big box store discontinued carrying about 6 years ago because of poor performance and too many customer complaints.  Generally no snap and click type of vinyl  flooring is offered under 5mm and smaller than about 45" x 7 inches.    Maybe try to google 36" x 6" vinyl flooring and you may get lucky